# Received, Hadoop command not found

Tags: macos, hadoop, cloudera

I am very new to Hadoop and try to install on my Mac OS X and when I run the command hadoop version in the terminal i get the message of  hadoop command not found.  Ive searched the help files here but am still having issues..

Below is my .bashrc file which i found a copy on the web

```
# Set Hadoop-related environment variables
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/bin/hadoop

# Set JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
# Add Hadoop bin/ directory to PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

and this is from my hadoop-env.sh file for the java location

```
# The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
```

My installation of hadoop is located in /usr/bin/hadoop

Answer (score 1):

```
$cd ~
$vi .bashrc

paste following to the end of the file

#Hadoop variables
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/bin/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
###end of paste

$ cd /usr/bin/hadoop/etc/hadoop
$ vi hadoop-env.sh

#modify JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/
```

more detail-
http://codesfusion.blogspot.in/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html